# useCallBack wrapped onSelect function is causing all components that have this function as a prop to re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have the following onSelect function, wrapped in useCallback...

```
const [descriptive, setDescriptive] = useState({})

  const handleSelectionsCall = useCallback((event, inputLabel) => {
    const { target: { value }} = event;
    var newVal = typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value;
    const lastItem = newVal[newVal.length -1]
    if (lastItem === 'Unselect') newVal = []
    const update = descriptive[inputLabel];
    const updatedDescriptive = {
      ...descriptive,
      [inputLabel]: {
        ...update,
        selected: newVal,
        error: newVal.length === 0 && ["Exchange", "Industry", "Sector"].includes(inputLabel) ? "At least one selection must be made" : ""
      }
    };
    setDescriptive(updatedDescriptive);
  }, [descriptive, setDescriptive]);
```

I am passing it to these three drop-down check select Material UI components.

```
<div className={colSize}>
  <CheckSelect
    selected={descriptive.Sector.selected}
    allSelections={allSectors}
    allSelected={
      descriptive.Sector.selected.length === allSectors.length
    }
    inputLabel="Sector"
    onSelect={handleSelectionsCall}
    labelFontSize={"120%"}
    extraOutlineSpace={"fil"}
    validationWarning={descriptive.Sector.error}
    size={smallWidth ? "small" : "medium"}
  />
</div>
<div className={colSize}>
  <CheckSelect
    selected={descriptive.Industry.selected}
    allSelections={descriptive.Industry.allSelections}
    allSelected={
      descriptive.Industry.selected.length === descriptive.Industry.allSelections.length
    }
    inputLabel="Industry"
    onSelect={handleSelectionsCall}
    labelFontSize={"120%"}
    extraOutlineSpace={"fill"}
    validationWarning={descriptive.Industry.error}
    size={smallWidth ? "small" : "medium"}
  />
</div>
<div className={colSize}>
  <CheckSelect
    selected={descriptive.Exchange.selected}
    allSelections={exchanges}
    allSelected={descriptive.Exchange.selected.length === 2}
    inputLabel="Exchange"
    onSelect={handleSelectionsCall}
    labelFontSize={"120%"}
    extraOutlineSpace={"filll"}
    validationWarning={descriptive.Exchange.error}
    size={smallWidth ? "small" : "medium"}
  />
</div>
```

The CheckSelect components are memoized (the following is a shortened version of full component)

```
export default memo(function CheckSelect({
    allSelections,
    selected,
    onSelect,
    inputLabel='',
    labelFontSize,
    extraOutlineSpace='',
    validationWarning='test',
    size,
    allSelected=false
  }) {
    console.log('render ' + inputLabel)

return (
<Select
  labelId="demo-multiple-checkbox-label"
  id="demo-multiple-checkbox"
  sx={selectFieldStyles(validationWarning)}
  multiple
  value={selected}
  onChange={e => onSelect(e, inputLabel)}
  input={<OutlinedInput label={inputLabel+extraOutlineSpace} />}
  renderValue={(selected) => {
    if (allSelected) return 'Any'
    return selected.join(', ')
  }}
  MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
{map selections}
</Select>
)
})
```

When I change one of the selections, the other two selections re-render, even though their props are not changing. Why is this happening?

I know it has to do with the handleSelectionsCall because if I comment this out from being passed to the CheckSelect, the other CheckSelects do not re-render when another CheckSelect is updated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've put `descriptive` in the dependencies list, and your function always calls `setDescriptive`, which updates `descriptive`, which means a new function has to be created. So the `useCallback` isn't serving any useful purpose.

To avoid that, don't use the state member `descriptive` in the function directly; use the callback form of `setDescriptive` instead [as shown in the documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state):

```
const handleSelectionsCall = useCallback(
    (event, inputLabel) => {
        const {
            target: { value },
        } = event;
        const newVal = typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value;
        const lastItem = newVal[newVal.length - 1];
        if (lastItem === "Unselect") {
            newVal = [];
        }
        setDescriptive((descriptive) => { // ***
            const update = descriptive[inputLabel];
            const updatedDescriptive = {
                ...descriptive,
                [inputLabel]: {
                    ...update,
                    selected: newVal,
                    error:
                        newVal.length === 0 &&
                        ["Exchange", "Industry", "Sector"].includes(
                            inputLabel
                        )
                            ? "At least one selection must be made"
                            : "",
                },
            };
            return updatedDescriptive;
        });
    },
    [] // ***
);
```

Notice that I've removed `descriptive` and `setDescriptive` from the dependencies list, because:

- `descriptive` - The function no longer uses it, it uses the parameter to its callback instead.
- `setDescriptive` - State setters from `useState` are *stable*, so there's no reason to list them in dependency lists.

Now, your `handleSelectionsCall` is stable, it won't cause unnecessary re-renders.